# How to succinctly convert an iterator over &str to a collection of String

Tags: rust, collections, iterator

I am new to Rust, and it seems very awkward to use sequences of functional transformations on strings, because they often return `&str`.

For example, here is an implementation in which I try to read lines of two words separated by a space, and store them into a container of tuples:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let s = std::io::stdin()
        .lines()
        .map(|l| l.unwrap())
        .map(|l| {
            l.split(" ")
                .collect_tuple()
                .map(|(a, b)| (a.to_string(), b.to_string()))
                .unwrap()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f6d370457cc3254195565f69047018c

Because `split` returns an iterator to `&str` objects, whose scope is the lambda used for the `map`, the only way I saw to return them was to manually convert them back to `string`s.  This seems really awkward.

Is there a better way to implement such a program?

Comment: Aside: if you split on a single character `split(' ')` is more efficient than `split(" ")` [and clippy will tell you too](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#single_char_pattern)

Comment: Note that "best practice" questions are often considered categorically off-topic. [Why is a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353) -- it seems like you may in fact have a narrow/specific technical problem here, so it might improve reception to lean into that and away from the "best practice" descriptor (and the accompanying excessive breadth).

Comment: You could also use `.split_once(' ')` instead of `.split(' ').collect_tuple()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust is explicit about allocation. The `String`s returned by the `lines()` iterator don't persist beyond the iterator chain, so you can't just store references into them. Therefore, logically, there needs to be a `to_string()` (or `to_owned`, or `String::from`) *somewhere*.

But putting it after the tuple creation is a bit awkward, because it requires you to call the function twice. You can turn the result of the `split()` into owned objects instead. This should work:

```
    .map(|l| {
        l.split(" ")
            .map(String::from)
            .collect_tuple()
            .unwrap()
    })
    .collect::<Vec<(_,_)>>();
```

Note that now you have to be explicit about the tuple type, though.